# Keeping tab bar on View after segue?

Tags: ios, swift, interface-builder, uitabbarcontroller

I have a tab bar controller, then a navigation controller, then a first view controller. This view controller has a tab bar as expected. However, when I segue from this view I lose the tab bar. I want it to retain its position on the other VC's stemming from this first view. Here is my IB:

[image]

I want the tab bar to also appear on the left VC after it is loaded via segue from the right VC,

How is this achieved as currently it disappears regardless of me setting the tab section at the bottom of the VC as shown above.

Answer (score 0):

From storyboard you establish a segue from starting view controller to Tab Bar Root View Controller. Then you use segue to pass the data to the specific item view controller

```
 override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    let vc = segue.destination as! TabBarRootViewController
    let vc1  = vc.viewControllers?[0] as! specificItemViewController
    vc1.destinationVariable = self.startingControllerVariable
```