# Pass Data From One TabbarVC to Another TabbarVC W/O losing Tabbar

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller

I want to pass photo data from one Viewcontroller(cameraVC) in a Tabbarcontroller to another Viewcontroller(mainVC) in the same Tabbarcontroller **without losing the tabbar after I perform the segue.**

**Setup:** 
*Tabbarcontroller

```
      -Navbarcontroller
      --mainVC (Tabbar Item)
      --cameraVC (Tabbar Item)
```

I must be able to use prepareForSegue and performSegue in cameraVC (This is how I am passing the data over to mainVC).

**What I have tried W/O success:**
[Keeping tab bar on View after segue?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43054215/keeping-tab-bar-on-view-after-segue), 
[Why TabBar hides after the segue?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35500866/why-tabbar-hides-after-the-segue/35501541)

**current implementation:**

```
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

    let destinationNavigationController = segue.destination as! UINavigationController
    let targetController = destinationNavigationController.topViewController as! HomeVC

   // if let homeVC = segue.destination as? HomeVC {
       if let imageDict = sender as? Dictionary<String, Any> {
            let imageData = imageDict["snapshotData"]
            targetController.imageData = imageData as? Data

      // }
    }
}

@IBAction func sendBtnPressed(_ sender: Any) {

   performSegue(withIdentifier: "goFeed", sender: ["snapshotData": photoData.removeValue(forKey: "photoData")])

    imageTaken.image = nil
    self.view.insertSubview(previewView, aboveSubview: imageView)
}
```

Comment: how much image data you need to pass ?

Comment: A single image at a time

Comment: if there is a single image to pass then you don't need to pass the `Data` to next vc just pass image direct to its similar object of next vc.

Comment: I must pass the data because the data will be used to post to my Database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I solved the problem was by creating a variable in my TabbarController which is globally recognized and used to pass the image data to the mainVC. This was the most viable solution for me to avoid creating duplicate views.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the `sender` argument of the `performSegue(_:, sender:)` method incorrectly. It should be the view controller initiating the segue. It looks like your `photoData` property belongs to the view controller initiating the segue, so just access it directly in the `prepareForSegue` method. So it would look like this:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

    let destinationNavigationController = segue.destination as! UINavigationController
    let targetController = destinationNavigationController.topViewController as! HomeVC

    if let imageData: Data = self.photoData["photoData"] as? Data {
        targetController.imageData = imageData
    }
}

@IBAction func sendBtnPressed(_ sender: Any) {

   performSegue(withIdentifier: "goFeed", sender: self)

    imageTaken.image = nil
    self.view.insertSubview(previewView, aboveSubview: imageView)
}
```

Comment: This does not work considering I NEED the data to be passed to the mainVC to be used as a post to my DB. It also did not help in maintaing the tabbar on segue